# How do I build a custom Sagemaker Image Container for gpu accelerated applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am currently in the process of building a custom container for a sagemaker training job, using amazon linux 2 as my base image. However, I could not find resources/examples online about this. I am currently struggling on the requirements of only installing the cuda toolkit but nvidia driver

I understand that there is a prebuild nvidia image which I can use as my base. but unfortunately, my application doesn't allow that. also conda may not be the best option as well. Please advice :)

Answer (score -1):

What requires you to start from scratch? Just make sure you have a really good reason, because it's extra work for you.
You could build on top of AWS's [Deep Learning Containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pre-built-containers-frameworks-deep-learning.html).
Or at the very least build on top of NVIDIA's NGC container, so you don't have to deal with CUDA installation - [Here's](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-efa-nccl-baseami-pipeline/blob/master/nvidia-efa-docker_base/ubuntu18.04/Dockerfile-cu11-pt20.10.sagemaker) an example of enabling an NGC container with high performance EFA networking driver and SageMaker.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info, and yes, I totally understand that. The reason why I was forced to consider it is because I needed time to convince the security guys in the place that I work that this is an okay approach, but at the same time, I still need to get work done. (a strange catch-22 situation). Would have built directly from the NGC in the first place under normal circumstances....